# Polymer 1.0.5: Select not working on paper-dropdown-menu

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I can't seem to set a default selected option, if needed. Read the [docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dropdown-menu) but no other properties, except for label works.

```
  <paper-dropdown-menu label="I Love:">
    <paper-menu class="dropdown-content" selectedItem="Heroes Reborn">
      <paper-item>Teen Wolf</paper-item>
      <paper-item>Heroes Reborn</paper-item>
      <paper-item>Once Upon a Time</paper-item>
    </paper-menu>
  </paper-dropdown-menu>
```

No matter if I set a value on `paper-item value="x"` then `<paper-menu selected="x">` nothing works. Do I need to run some other script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting selected to an integer should work. If you want to select the second item set `<paper-menu selected="1">`.

If you want to use `value` instead of an integer index, set `attr-for-selected="value"`

```
    <paper-menu attr-for-selected="value" selected="heroes" class="dropdown-content">
        <paper-item value="teen">Teen Wolf</paper-item>
        <paper-item value="heroes">Heroes Reborn</paper-item>
        <paper-item value="once">Once Upon a Time</paper-item>
    </paper-menu>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out later and let you know.

Comment: `<paper-dropdown-menu selected="1" label="I Love:">` does not selects anything

Comment: Put the `selected` into the `<paper-menu>` tag not the `<paper-dropdown-menu>` tag.

Comment: Thanks. That work. Not related to this question but how can you bind the `selected='{{value}}>` Possible?

Comment: I have edited my answer to address your latest question.

Comment: :) I'm happy I could help