# Assigning a variable value to a paper-item

Tags: dart, polymer, angular-dart

I'm trying to assign a object id to a list item so that I can look it up when it's selected. There is an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982671/polymer-1-0-5-select-not-working-on-paper-dropdown-menu) that uses a literal. It also works for me. This code doesn't set the value:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Style">
  <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" attr-for-selected="value" selected="2">
    <paper-item *ngFor="let style of styles" value="{{ style.id }}">
        {{ style.name }}
    </paper-item>
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

If I code `value="1"` or `value="test"`, it appears when I inspect in the browser. If it's set as above, nothing appears, not even an empty value. I've also tried creating String `test=1;` in the Angular component and using `value="{{ test }}"`. It also does not appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this doesn't work, then it might be a timing issue:

```
attr.value="{{style.id}}"
```